# CiviCRM API V3 : Translate Two Digit State to State_Province_id?

Tags: import, data-import

I'm using civimigrate for a pretty intense migration into CiviCRM and I have hit something of a puzzler.

I have a table with addresses that I am matching to contacts, but I cannot seem to find a way to map a state abbreviation (AL,MD,FL) to an id for the api.

I was hoping to find something in the API explorer to paste into my import, but I can't seem to find out where the API calls for translating state abbreviations into ids live.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response. I ended up doing something similar before seeing your response by creating a pre-processed source table with raw SQL queries.  My actual use case involved a few thousand entries, not all of them US based.

I split up my address records into US/Non-US, then joined the US table on LIKE where country_id=1228, and the non-us table on LIKE where country_id <> 1228, ignoring state/province for non-us records, then recombined them both, now with proper country and state/province ids.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('StateProvince', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'abbreviation' => array('IN' => array("AL", "MD", "FL")),
  'country_id' => 1228,
));
```

Note that you should specify `country_id` as state abbreviations are not globally unique.